Counting pairs of integers
(a)How many pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers satisfy $5a \geq 6b$ and $a < 360$?
(b)How many pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers satisfy $\sqrt{a} \geq b$ and $a \leq 2024$?
Given the condition $b \leq \frac{5x}{6}$:

When $x = 359$, we have $b \leq 299$, thus $299$ pairs.
When $x = 355$, we have $b \leq 295$, resulting in $295$ pairs.
However, for $x = 354$, the inequality $b \leq 295$ implies $294 + 1$ pairs, due to the integer rounding.

Further analysis:

For $x = 2$, we have $b \leq 1$, hence $1$ pair.
For $x = 1$, $b = 0$ which is not valid as $b$ must be a positive integer.

It is observed that an additional pair is obtained when $x$ is a multiple of $6$. From $1$ to $359$, there are $59$ multiples of $6$. This is computed as:
$$
\text{Number of multiples of 6} = \left\lfloor \frac{359}{6} \right\rfloor = 59
$$
I don't know if what I wrote for (a) is correct. As in (b) I'm not sure how to approach it. Any help is appreciated.

For $(a)$, how many terms are there in the summation? Are there 358 terms from 1 to 358? Or 300 terms?  If the latter, which terms are missing?

@CalvinLin I found 358 terms

@CalvinLin I see my mistake. Some terms are missing from the sum. How can I correct it?

So we have $b \le \frac {5a}6;a < 360$ and there are $[\frac {5a}6]$ such possible values of $b$ for each value of $a$.
So the number of pairs is $\sum_{a=1}^{360-1}[\frac {5a}6]$.  Now if $a = 6q + r; 0\le r < 6$ then $[\frac {5a}6]= [5q + \frac {5r}6]=5q + 0,0,1,2,3,4$ (depending on if $r = 0,1,2,3,4,5$)
So $\sum_{a=6q}^{6q+5}[\frac {5a}6]= (5q + 0) + (5q+0) + .... + (5q +3)+(5q+4)= 30q + 10$.
So $\sum_{a = 0}^{360-1} [\frac {5a}6]= \sum_{q=0}^{59}(\sum_{a=6q}^{6q+5}[\frac {5a}6])=$
$\sum_{q=0}^{59} (30q + 10)= 600 + 30\sum_{q=0}^{59}q= 600 + 30\cdot \frac{59\cdot 60}2=53700$.
.... Someone might want to proof read my arithmetic and carrying the right values from line to line but I'm pretty sure my strategy is sound.
===
(A complete redo for b) )
We have $a\le 2024 = 45^2 -1$ and $b\le \sqrt a < 45$
Now for any $a$ there is a unique $n$ so that $n^2 \le a < (n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$.  And the number of $b$s where $b \le \sqrt a$ will be then number of $b$s where $b\le n \le \sqrt a < n+1$.  And that number is $n$.
So we can set this up that
$\sum_{a=1}^{45^2-1} |\{(b,a)|b\le \sqrt a\}|=$
$\sum_{n=1}^{44} (\sum_{k=0;a=n^2+k}^{2n}|\{(b,a)|b\le n\}|)=$
$\sum_{n=1}^{44}(\sum_{k=0}^{2n} n)=$
$\sum_{n=1}^{44}((2n+1)n)=$
$\sum_{n=1}^{44}(2n^2 + n)=$
$2\frac {44\cdot 45\cdot 89}6 +\frac {44\cdot 45}2=59730$
====
Both are pretty similar.  You have $b \le C(a); a < U$ where $C(a)$ is some conditional (in a) $C(a) = \frac {5a}6$ and in b) $C(a)=\sqrt a$) and $U$ is an upper limit of $U$.
Thus in both of these the number of pairs is $\sum_{a=1}^{a< U} [C(a)]$.
And in both of these there is a range of values for $f(n)\le a < f(n+1)$ we have $[C(a)]=h_{n,a}$ where $h_{n,a}$ is a constant or something very simple in terms of $n$.
In a) we have for any $6n\le a < 6(n+1)$ we have $[\frac {5a}6]=5n + r_i$ where if $a = 6n+0,1,2,3,4,5$ then $r_i = 0,0,1,2,3,4$ and so $h_{n,a} = n+r_i$.
In b) we have for any $n^2 \le a <(n+1)^2$ we have $[\sqrt a] = n$.  So $h_{n,a} = n$.
And in each case the upper limit $U: a < U; a \le U-1$ is always a value of $f(M+1)$ for so number $M$.  In a) we have $a < 360 = 6\times 60$ and $M= 60-1=59$.  And in b) we have $a \le 2024 < 2025=45^2$ and $M =45-1=44$.
So we can then do
$\sum_{a=1}^{U-1} [C_a]=$
$\sum_{n=1}^{M} (\sum_{a=f(n)}^{f(n+1)-1} h_{n,a})=$
$\sum_{n=1}^M (f(n+1)-f(n))h_{n,a}$ with some variation
$= W_n$
That is... in case a) where $h_{n,a}= n+r_i$ then $\sum_{a=f(n)}^{f(n+1)-1} h_{n,a}=\sum_{a=6n}^{6(n+1)-1} (n+r_i)=6n + r_0+r_1+...+r_5 = 6n+ 10=W_n$.
And in case b) where $h_{n,a}=n$ we have $\sum_{a=f(n)}^{f(n+1)-1} h_{n,a}=\sum_{a=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1} n = (2n+1)\times n=2n^2 +n = W_n$.
And the finally solution is
$\sum_{n=1}^M W_n$.
In a) that is $\sum_{n=1}^{59} (6n+10)$ and in b) that is $\sum_{n=1}^{44}(2n^2 +n)$
Usint the formulas that $\sum_{n=1}^M n = \frac {M(M+1)}2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^M n^2 = \frac {M(M+1)(2M+1)}6$
The results fall out

For (a), you missed $r=5$ entirely. The correct answer is $53700$, and you can see my answer and the comments, or this. I cannot follow your reasoning for part (b), but the correct answer is $59730$. See this.

Oh, right.  I got 5 and 6 confuse.  And $59730 = 2\frac {44\cdot 45\cdot 89}6 +\frac {44\cdot 45}2$ which is my answer.

Try rereading my explanation for b) again.  The reasoning is sound and it did get the correct answer with no error.   Did I need to explicitly state that $2024 = 45^2 -1$?  Or that if $n^2 \le a < (n+1)^2$ and $b \le \sqrt a$ that that means $b \le n$?

I don't know what I was doing. It is clear, I understand now. @fleablood.

You expect $299$ terms, but you got $358$. Some terms are not there. Which ones? Let us do small cases.
For $b=1$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 1=1.2$.
For $b=2$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 2=2.4$.
For $b=3$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 3=3.6$.
For $b=4$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 4=4.8$.
For $b=5$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 5=6.0$.
For $b=6$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 2=7.2$.
For $b=7$, we have $a\geq 1.2\times 7=8.4$.
Voila! The first few terms look like $(359-1)+(359-2)+(359-3)+(359-4)+(359-5)+(359-7)+(359-8)+(359-9)+\dots$. You should be able to see the issue here. A jump happens every time $b$ is a multiple of $5$. Can you see how to repair your argument from here and see which terms are missing?
Hope this helps. :)

I got 44909 pairs. Is this correct?

@math.enthusiast9: you should get the sum$$(1+2+3+\dots+358)-(5+11+17+23+\dots+353)=53700$$

I see my mistake. Thank you for helping me. Could you also help me with (b)?

@math.enthusiast9: Try a similar thing and see if you have any issues.

Is it 59730 pairs ?

@math.enthusiast9 Yup.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So this is how we calculate the no. of pairs: $\sum_{a=1}^{2024} \left\lfloor \sqrt{a} \right\rfloor$
